# Using groovy evaluated variables without retrieving them in a java servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, groovy

I'm writing a Java servlet to parse an HTML template and generate a final HTML file and present it on the browser. I'm supposed to use Groovy to process some script elements within that template.

In this case, the script element is something like this:

```
<script type=server/groovy">
    import package
   def id = request.getParameter("id")
   obj = Dog.getDog(id) //This will retrieve a Dog object depending on the id
</script>
```

Within my servlet, I can easily access and use the dog variable with something like this:

```
private String processScript(String hmtlContent, HttpServletRequest request){
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setVariable("request", request);
    Dog dog = (Dog)binding.getVariable("dog");

    //do stuff with dog...
}
```

Then further on on the template I have other uses of this dog object, using $-expressions:

```
<body>
    <h1 title="${dog.color}">${dog.color}</h1>
</body>
```

Using the snippet above I can achieve the wanted result, however, I want this code to work with whatever variable I want. For example, if I only change the variable dog to doggo in the script element my code no longer works.

So my question is: is it possible to evaluate the script element, have the variable be put on the variable stack at run time without initializing it in my servlet, and then evaluate those $-expressions further on without explicitly initializing the variable in the servlet?

Comment: can you elaborate on the full picture of your setup? 
How exactly the "scripts" are loaded and executed, and how the HTML-template is being called?